# Plot: Show specific values in y axis

Tags: plotting

I need to plot a list of points and I am using `ListLinePlot`. *Mathematica* decides which values on the y axis are labeled.  How can I show labels for the exact *y* value of each point?

Comment: try this again http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html

Comment: that was the solution! thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have only a couple of points you could try

```
data = {1.2, 4.3, 5.3, 2.721, 7.32, 1.7, 4.9};

ListLinePlot[
 data,
 Ticks -> {Automatic, data},
 GridLines -> {Automatic, data},
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]

However, if points are not sufficiently apart ticks will be overwritten. Therefore I would recommend to use `Tooltip`.

```
ListLinePlot[
 Tooltip @ data,
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Setting the mouse pointer on any point you can see its exact value.

With not too many points you might consider

```
points =
  Text[#2, {##}] & @@@ Transpose[{Range@Length@data, data}] /.
   {a_, b_} :> {a - 0.3, b - 0.3};

ListLinePlot[Tooltip@data,
 Epilog -> points,
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]

**An unsuccessful rebellion against the closing votes:**

```
data =
  Round[Table[Re[Zeta[1/2 + I x]], {x, 20, 40, 1}], 0.01];

points =
  Text[Framed[#2, FrameMargins -> {{3, 3}, {0, 0}}, Background -> White],
       {##}] & @@@ Transpose[{Range[20, 40], data}] /.
         {a_, b_} :> {a, b - 0.12} /.                   
            Framed[a_, b__] :> Framed[PaddedForm[a, {2, 2}], b];

ListLinePlot[
 Tooltip@data,
 Epilog -> points,
 DataRange -> {20, 40},
 Filling -> Axis,
 FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], LightBlue],
 Frame -> True,
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 ImageSize -> 600,
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Blue, PointSize[Large]],
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
 PlotRangePadding -> {{0.9, 0.5}, {0.3, 0.1}},
 PlotStyle -> GrayLevel@0.7]
```

[image]

Comment: As an alternative to `{a_, b_} :> {a, b - 0.12}` you could just add an offset to `Text`. Try `Text[..., {0, 1.75}]]`

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by @eldo there is a risk of the labels overlapping. In addition to the methods he mentioned to deal with this, you can reduce the likelihood of overlap by using a `Frame` and alternating labels between left and right `FrameTicks`.

```
data = Round[#, .01] & /@ RandomReal[{0, 7}, {9, 2}] // Sort;

yValues = data[[All, 2]] // Sort;

{yLeft, yRight} = ({yValues, ""} //
       Flatten // Partition[#, 2] & //
       Transpose) /. "" -> Sequence[];
(* padded to handle cases with odd number of points *)

ListLinePlot[Tooltip /@ data,
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
 FrameTicks -> {{yLeft, yRight}, {Automatic, None}},
 GridLines -> {Automatic, yValues},
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]